# Listing mysql records with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, do-while

I am attempting to create two lists of records from a database in the same page like so:

```
<?php do {   ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>

<?php do {   ?>
<div>
<h1><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $row['email']; ?></p>
</div>
<?php } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>
```

While the first loop works fine, the second time around (creating the div) the do-while loop does not return any data. How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead, i.e. removes the row as it goes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a `mysql_data_seek($result, 0);` between the two loops to reset the result so you can read it again.

Be warned, if the query didn't return any rows, `mysql_data_seek` will give you a warning.  Check whether there were rows returned before using it.

Also be warned, your loops are backwards.  You need to fetch, *then* display.  :P  Otherwise, each loop's first iteration will spit out an empty row.  Use `while (...) { }` rather than `do { } while (...)`.

(*Also* be warned, **`mysql_query` is crap.  Stop using it.  Please.  For all our sakes.**  The mysqli extension does the same thing, can work almost identically, [and -- unlike mysql -- is actively maintained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  Plus, when you finally get around to learning to use prepared statements (and *you should learn to use prepared statements*), mysqli has them.)

Comment: "when you finally get around to learning to use prepared statements" - absolutely on point assessment there... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different variable naming for the `$result`, e.g `$result1` and `$result2`

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_assoc returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead, i.e. removes the row as it gets it. A second iteration won't find rows.

This should work, maybe not the best way (I've used a db class forever).

`$result2 = $result;`

On iteration 2 use `mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);`

Comment: ah, there was a better way - mysql_data_seek. +1 to cHao